# unable to connect to k8s server while using kubectl cmd with changed ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

my vm ip keeps changing from time to time and that can not be avoided. My earlier ip was 192.168.1.75 and i was able to connect to k8s using  "kubectl get pods" and output was correct.

But now I am in a different network with different IP 10.160.194.67. When I try to connect, I get below error

```
/root# kubectl get pod
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.75:6443: connect: no route to host
/root#
```

to fix that i just updated the new ip in  /root/.kube/config file. but now it complains about the cerificate

```
/root# kubectl   get pod
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 192.168.1.75, not 10.160.194.67
/root#
```

I know this certificate is no more valid with the new ip. my question is how to get new certificate and replace here for this particular ip?

As I said, I need a solution for this so that whenever my IP changes, I need to modify my config file to work. Keeping IP same is not possible in my case.

Thanks

Comment: SO is for programming problems. Please try asking at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: k8s is not made for setups where the IP keeps changing... you will need to change the IP on few places, like k8s setup, traefik, metallb, also regenerate/reissue certificates every time the IP changes.. (which is all in the DOCS for kubernetes, on how to accomplish).. Assumption is that this is a setup of only 1 node?

Answer (score 0):

k8s is not made for setups where the IP keeps changing... you will need to change the IP on few places, like k8s setup, traefik, metallb, also regenerate/reissue certificates every time the IP changes.. (which is all in the DOCS for kubernetes, on how to accomplish)

for your current issue, you can use:

```
kubeadm certs check-expiration # to check certificates
kubeadm certs renew -h # help on renewal
kubeadm certs renew all # to renew all certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

The command below can solve it for you: (run in the host)

```bash
curl -vk --resolve <NEW-IP>:6443:127.0.0.1  https://<NEW-IP>:6443/ping
```

Then update the IP in your `kubeconfig` file. Then you should be able to continue connecting your cluster.